# How to hide blank mailmerge address fields in letters

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have been looking into this all morning and am really hoping there is a simple solution to this.
I have a document that has 7 mailmerge address fields; addline1, addline2, addline3, addline4, addline5, addline6, Postcode.
Where the address only has addlines 1-4 and a postcode, I'm getting blank lines between addline4 and the postcode. 
Obviously if all addlines are used, it looks fine.

I have tried setting up if then else rules and I made the assumption that all addresses would have at least 3 lines included so the first rule in place was {If {MERGEFIELD Addline4 } <> "" {MERGEFIELD Addline4} {MERGEFIELD Postcode}}
This worked in scenarios where the address was 5 lines but if more or less, it would not behave and would either not show the postcode at all, OR show it twice. I think I'm getting close to working it out but it's driving me mad!

I would have thought that this was a common issue with mailmerge address fields but have searched here and googled and I can only seem to find similar questions with no solutions attached. Is anyone able to help at all?
Thanks

Comment: Are you putting the address in an address block? If not, you should just be able to put each merge field on a separate line (with no IF statement or anything else other than whitespace) and Word should suppress blank lines as default.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I have tried both, most recently the address block and it is not surpressing blank lines. The mergefields are coming direct from an external system so I wonder if it is passing back the data field as an empty row/line perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Word’s mailmerge suppresses blank lines. However, there are limitations:

- acts only on paragraphs that contain only mergefields and white
  space (e.g. spaces, tabs, manual line breaks) and in which all
  mergefields are blank;
- does not occur when the field is nested inside another field (e.g. IF
  fields and INCLUDETEXT fields); and
- does not suppress empty table rows or empty lines in the address
  block field.

Comment: I had to change my line breaks to paragraph breaks to get the blank suppression to work. Also tried Hieu Pham's answer, which may have changed the document default. (MS 365 Apps for enterprise, Word version 2108).

Answer (score 1):

I find doing the following to be effective:

```
{ IF (ADDRESS1) <> "" "(ADDRESS1)
"}{ IF (ADDRESS2) <> "" "(ADDRESS2)
"}{ IF (ADDRESS3) <> "" "(ADDRESS3)
"}{ IF (ADDRESS4) <> "" "(ADDRESS4)
"}{ IF (ADDRESS5) <> "" "(ADDRESS5)
"}{ IF (ADDRESS6) <> "" "(ADDRESS6)
"}{ IF (POSTCODE) <> "" "(POSTCODE)
"}
```

This way, if ADDRESS5 & ADDRESS6 are NULL it will bump POSTCODE up without leaving any blank lines.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my steps here.
Actually, Microsoft Word has this function but it is hiddend.
I took pictures as instruction but I don't know how to post them here.
So please read by text:

- Step1: Right-click to empty space of ribbon then chose "**Customize the Ribbon**"
- Step2: Chose "All commands" at "Chose command from" box. Scroll down then select "Mail merge..."
- Step3: On the right of this Window select "New group", you'll see new folder name "New group" appears in the right box. Right-click on it then select Rename. Put what ever you want to rename it.
- Step4: Select "Add>>" then "OK"
- Step5: Insert Mail merge Field as normal. Then find to new function that you just creat on Ribbon. Click on it then chose option 3 "Merge the data with the document".

Then let Word do its job.

Comment: In Step 5, I would add, "Click on the Merge button, then select 'Don't print blank lines when data field are empty.'" I'm not clear if suppressing blank lines is the default, or if setting this through the ribbon option_changes_ the default for the document, but after doing it once, subsequent merges were without blanks.